# NodeJS - MongoDB computation overhead

Tags: node.js, performance, mongodb

I have a scenario in which I have to update 2 mongodb collections.
There are 2 collections: Ads, Likes

**Scenario 1:** I insert a document in **likes** table with the **ad._id** and **user._id** and on successful insertion I update the Ad's property likesCount with like's length using the query **db.likes.find({ad._id}).count()**. After that I will query **db.ads.find()** to fetch all ad's records. Ad's document will have the respective likes count already in them.

**Scenario 2:** I only insert a document in **likes** table with the **ad._id** and **user._id**. After that I will query **db.ads.find()** to fetch all ad's records and process each Ad's document to set the likesCount field on run time with the query **db.likes.find({ad._id}).count()**.

I want to know which scenario has more overhead in terms of computation and processing given that All Ads query will be hit only 1 time in a day.

Comment: The first use case seems open to race condition. In addition, remember that MongoDB does not have transaction. So you have to handle possible failure in the middle of your "scenario". That being said, I think this is an instance of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): they are _many_ different way to solve your issue. But it is hard to say without knowing your _requirements_. For example, do you really need real-time update of the "like counter" -- or would be a few hours lag acceptable ? Do you really need _exact_ count, or some _approximation_ would be sufficient ?

Comment: I dont need the like counter in real time